# Pycharm - how to move project pane on the right?

Tags: pycharm

I want to show the project pane on the right, how do I do it?

My [google search](https://www.google.com.vn/search?newwindow=1&q=pycharm+project+pane+on+the+right&oq=pycharm+project+pane+on+the+right&gs_l=psy-ab.3...27782.30339.0.30728.14.14.0.0.0.0.262.1463.0j10j1.11.0....0...1.1.64.psy-ab..6.0.0....0.FI6xITRWQbo) is little helpful so I asked here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply Click on Project pane and drag it into right side..

you can view it on right side,

**Click and Start drag**
[image: Click and drag]

**put it,**

[image]